How to unfold band structure of supercell in Quantum Espresso for noncollinear case?
I am using from Quantum Espresso to calculate band structure of supercells. In order to compare the band structures of supercell (including defects) to that of unitcell, I need to unfold the band structure of supercell. I used from unfold-x  for calculations without spin orbit coupling. It worked very well. Then I wanted to get unfolded band structure of supercell including SOC, unfold-x code gave error Non-collinear not implemented.So, I have to find other code which can work together with Quantum Espresso to unfold band structure for Non-colliniear case. Do you have any ideas?
